# Running X11 apps on a screen with limited bit depth

Tags: x11, window-manager, display

This is a bit of an esoteric query, but I want to export the X11 display from my Raspberry Pi to an old Mac capable of only 256 colours.  That's fine as far as it goes - but the colours are so mangled on the Mac monitor that the apps are unusable and unrecognisable.
Is it possible to configure Gnome to use no more than 16 colours (just to be on the safe side)?  Is there a theme for Gnome which I could use to do what I want?  Or, better yet, can I uninstall Gnome and run an email client like Sylpheed using something like twm?
The errors I get in Xorg.0.log (as suggested below) are:

```
~ $ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[262851.949] _XSERVTransSocketOpenCOTSServer: Unable to open socket for inet6
[262851.950] _XSERVTransOpen: transport open failed for inet6/raspberrypi:0
[262851.950] _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: failed to open listener for inet6
[262851.963] 
X.Org X Server 1.12.4
Release Date: 2012-08-27
[262851.967] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[262851.968] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-2-mx5 armv7l Debian
[262851.969] Current Operating System: Linux raspberrypi 3.18.7+ #755 PREEMPT Thu Feb 12 17:14:31 GMT 2015 armv6l
[262851.971] Kernel command line: dma.dmachans=0x7f35 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=656 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=416 bcm2708.boardrev=0xe bcm2708.serial=0x14e05b6a smsc95xx.macaddr=B8:27:EB:E0:5B:6A bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 sdhci-bcm2708.emmc_clock_freq=250000000 vc_mem.mem_base=0x1ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x20000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,4800 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p6 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait
[262851.979] Build Date: 11 February 2015  09:31:17PM
[262851.980] xorg-server 2:1.12.4-6+deb7u6 (Julien Cristau <jcristau@debian.org>) 
[262851.982] Current version of pixman: 0.33.1
[262851.983]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[262851.984] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[262851.999] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Apr  7 15:54:47 2016
[262852.000] (II) Loader magic: 0xb6f09cf0
[262852.000] (II) Module ABI versions:
[262852.000]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[262852.000]    X.Org Video Driver: 12.1
[262852.001]    X.Org XInput driver : 16.0
[262852.001]    X.Org Server Extension : 6.0
[262852.006] List of video drivers:
[262852.009]    fbturbo
[262852.011]    fbdev
[262852.012] (II) LoadModule: "fbturbo"
[262852.021] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbturbo_drv.so
[262852.027] (II) Module fbturbo: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[262852.027]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 0.3.1
[262852.027]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[262852.027]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 12.1
[262852.027] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[262852.028] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[262852.032] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[262852.032]    compiled for 1.12.1, module version = 0.4.2
[262852.032]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 12.0
[262852.033] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbturbo
[262852.033] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbturbo
[262852.034] No devices to configure.  Configuration failed.
[262852.036] Server terminated with error (2). Closing log file.
```

Comment: You should be able to configure gnome or similar to be more visible through some "accessibility" option. This usually provides high-contrast and big font features for people with restricted eyesight.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask the X server to use only 8-bit depth. In your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file:

```
Section "Screen"
        Identifier "Screen0"
        DefaultDepth    8
EndSection
```

Comment: Yeah - I saw that.  Trouble is, I don't have an xorg.conf file.  If I create one, will it use it automatically?

Comment: It should (edited answer to include path). If this doesn't work, look for errors in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, maybe my snippet is "too minimal" :)

Comment: Yup.  Tried it.  Didn't work, sadly.

Comment: And the errors are?

Comment: I've plugged them in to the original question above.  Thank you for your help by the way.

Comment: Strangely, it doesn't mention finding the config file. Can you post the original (working) log? Probably not inline, but using a pastebin.